# Empty string in Regex C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following Regex-pattern: `"[A-TVWZ]"`. I need it to accept also Empty strings `""`, how can I insert that in my pattern? I need it for my DataGridView, because when the User leaves the cell without writing anythig it gets an error in validating...

Comment: can give an example of the string that contains *that* `empty string`?

Comment: Are you sure that »Empty string or any string *containing* A–T, V, W or Z« is the pattern you really want to match?

Comment: yes, so either the User writes the right letter or he leaves it empty... because else the cell would give an error in the Datagridview....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe this is too simple; I would check for empty strings *without* regular expressions.

E.g.:

```
if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( myString ) || Regex.IsMatch( "[A-TVWZ]", myString )
{
    ....
}
```

See:

- [`String.IsNullOrEmpty` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty).
- [`Regex.IsMatch` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch).

Answer (score 6):

Try this `"[A-TVWZ]?"` or `"^[A-TVWZ]?$"`

The Question mark (`?`) will ensure that the pattern match zero or 1 time. So, the zero times means the empty string.

Comment: Would "zero matches" also mean other patterns that are _not_ empty strings?

Comment: no, it will only match when the pattern matches, or the string is empty.

Comment: As written here, no. This regular expression admits the language `'','A','B',...,'T','V','W','Z'` and nothing else.

Comment: No, it would also match `U`, for example.

Comment: The other way of writing this (if you want to make it more obvious that the empty string is an allowable match) is `([A-TVWZ]|)` - that is, alternation with the empty string.

Comment: Li-aung Yip: That'd be `[A-TVWZ]|^$`, if you actually wanted to alternate with an empty string (would have been my solution too). Remember that regexes match *substrings* by default (excluding a certain method in a certain language starting with J).

Comment: @Joey: You're right. How embarrassing. (It's worth clarifying that it will match `U` in the sense of matching the empty string in front of `U`, not `U` itself.)

Answer (score 3):

The pure regex way of doing this would be

```
[A-TVWZ]|^$
```

which will either match one of the aforementioned letters or the empty string. Your comment indicates that the user can only enter a single character anyway, so another option would be

```
^[A-TVWZ]?$
```

which is similar to Waqas' answer. *However*, this one would not introduce other strings that might match because of the anchors.